# Contracting with a prototype maker in China from the USA

Tags: international, patents

I have a product that I want to build a prototype for.

How do I protect myself if I am contracting a company in China to develop the product? I am in the US. How do I prevent them from stealing my idea, which will be in patent pending state?

Comment: Get a lawywer that specializes in that. Also, Chinese copyright laws are... notoriously flimsy.

Comment: @Trish - I know that you know that the relevant law would be patent not copyright.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite true, but chinese trademark and patent laws are even *worse*

Comment: They have been improving over the last few years.

Answer (score 4):

Protect against what? A US patent would, theoretically, let you try to stop anyone in the US from importing a product that infringes one of its claims. To try to stop manufacturer in an other location from producing a product and selling it other than in the US you either need a patent in the location if manufacture or or selling.

Of course you can also try to accomplish this by contract with the manufacturer. They may honor a contract and to not sell other than to you. But if are wildly successful you won’t be able to stop a different manufacturer in China, Vietnam or anywhere else.

One bit of advice might be to get good IP coverage for anything made, sold, offered for sale, imported or used in the US via US patents and be content with wild success in one of the largest markets protectable under one patent.

Some people advocate breaking your design down into interconnectable components and have different makers in different areas make each with final assembly in the US. Others say just go fast and make money while you can. Also you can license to a big company with some clout and money for attorneys. You get much less per unit but push many costs and hassles to them.